# What are examples of interview questions that employers ask for an entry level payroll clerk?

Tags: interviewing, entry-level

I applied for an entry level payroll clerk position, and I want to be prepared for an interview.
What are the possible interview questions that the employer will ask candidates for an entry level payroll clerk position? The posting asks for high school diploma, excellent organizational, oral communication, interpersonal, and the Microsoft Office skills, **but it doesn't say that knowledge or prior experience in payroll is required** (This is the reason why I applied for the position even though I have no prior experience in payroll).

In this case, what would be the possible interview questions that the employers can ask during the interview?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I just google [What are examples of interview questions that employers ask for an entry level payroll clerk?](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/10-interview-questions-payroll-administration-10809.html) and selected the first result. There are 290k results just by pasting your questions title in google and I am sure most of the first page is useful information.

Comment: The special thing about this posting is that it is not asking for prior knowledge or experience in payroll. Most of those interview questions are for people who already have years of experience in payroll, so I don't think they would apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really your question is easily answered by reviewing the job positing and making sure you know about each subject the job positing request. If there is one or two subjects you don't know. Do some studding before the the interview and brush up on the other stuff just to be safe.

In an entry level job they will train you to do all the important stuff they need you to be able to do. They just want you to be a competent person.

Be sure of what you know and express your interest in learning the stuff you don't.

Its not like you are interviewing for anything advanced and requires prior knowledge of many subjects.